# Why my calendar cancel event not working as expected with .ics file

Tags: python, icalendar

I'm trying to create new invite and then send cancel invite using python `iCalendar` package. New invite working as expected, but `cancel invite` is not working, instead its creating duplicate invite.

Invite `.ics` looks as below, which i'm sending as attachment in email

**New invite**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Calendar invite//mxm.dk//
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:[CONFIRMED]: Python meeting calendar
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20210606T080000
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20210606T170000
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20210604T165119Z
UID:74cf83e4-e4ff-42dd-97d2-fc5964661e37
SEQUENCE:1622850679
DESCRIPTION:Event1 details
LOCATION:Portland\, Oregon
ORGANIZER;CN="Max Rasmussen";ROLE=CHAIR;SENT-BY="MAILTO:tester-grimsby@tester.com":MAILTO:karthikvadla16@gmail.com
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

**Cancel invite**

I'm making sure to pass below properties as recommended

- Same UID of the event
- Method: CANCEL
- Status: CANCELLED
- Organizer: is set.
- Sequence: incremented (to set priority)

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Calendar invite//mxm.dk//
METHOD:CANCEL
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:[CANCELLED]: Python meeting calendar
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20210606T080000
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20210606T170000
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20210604T165432Z
UID:74cf83e4-e4ff-42dd-97d2-fc5964661e37
SEQUENCE:1622850872
DESCRIPTION:Event1 details
LOCATION:Portland\, Oregon
ORGANIZER;CN="Max Rasmussen";ROLE=CHAIR;SENT-BY="MAILTO:tester-grimsby@tester.com":MAILTO:karthikvadla16@gmail.com
STATUS:CANCELLED
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I tried out all work-arounds as suggested on stackoverflow, still not able to resolve the issue.
Can someone help me, what i'm missing here?

Here is my source code

```
def create_calendar_invite(calendar_event: dict):
    """Method to build calendar invite"""
    calendar = Calendar()
    calendar.add("prodid", "-//Grimsby Calendar invite//mxm.dk//")
    calendar.add("version", "2.0")

    status = calendar_event.get("status")
    if status == "CANCELLED":
        calendar.add("method", "CANCEL")
    else:
        calendar.add("method", "REQUEST")

    event = __create_calendar_event_object(calendar_event)
    calendar.add_component(event)
    return calendar.to_ical()


def __create_calendar_event_object(calendar_event):
    """Method to build calendar event object"""
    event = Event()
    event.add("uid", calendar_event["event_uid"])

    # set priority of the event
    status = calendar_event.get("status")
    if status == "CANCELLED":
        event.add("sequence", 1)
    else:
        event.add("sequence", 0)

    # status can be TENTATIVE/CONFIRMED/CANCELLED
    # status = calendar_event["status"]

    current_timestamp = datetime.now()
    # organizer = vCalAddress('MAILTO:karthikvadla16@gmail.com')

    # "SENT-BY", for specifying another calendar
    # user that is acting on behalf of the "Organizer"
    # organizer.params['sent-by'] = vText(f"MAILTO:tester-grimsby@{os.getenv('DOMAIN_NAME')}")
    # organizer.params['cn'] = vText('Max Rasmussen')
    # organizer.params['role'] = vText('CHAIR')
    event.add('organizer', "karthikvadla16@gmail.com")

    event.add("status", status)
    event.add("summary", f"[{status}]: {calendar_event['summary']}")

    event.add("dtstart", datetime.fromtimestamp(calendar_event["start_timestamp"]))
    event.add("dtend", datetime.fromtimestamp(calendar_event["end_timestamp"]))
    event.add("dtstamp", current_timestamp)
    event.add("location", vText(calendar_event["location"]))
    event.add("description", vText(calendar_event["description"]))
    return event
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Update source code in my actual question. @drum

Answer (score 0):

Getting an application to recognise an update or cancel requires a combination of

- Exact SAME UID as original invite.
- Incremented SEQUENCE from the last update. IE if there was a modification inbetween then SEQUENCE would be > 1
- LAST-MODIFIED https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.7.3
- Email recipient must be an ATTENDEE and there must be adequate ATTENDEE details.  See [Icalendar ICS update not working in google calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712929/icalendar-ics-update-not-working-in-google-calendar/49585109#49585109)